# efficient collection lookup and index creation in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a very high volume of data coming in to my database, up to 1,000 documents per second. And when I receive each one I am trying to efficiently check if there is already a collection for that type of document based on a field in the document and then if not I want to create a few indexes on that collection. Basically I am wondering how long it takes to create an index on an empty collection and if there is any faster way to check if there is a collection with a specified name.

```
def insert_new_doc(json_doc):
  collection_name = json_doc["collection_name"]
  coll = tlm_db_connection[collection_name]

  # create indexes in background if the collection doesn't exist
  if tlm_db_connection.system.namespaces.find( { name : collection_name } ) == None:
      coll.ensure_index([('time_stamp', pymongo.DESCENDING)], background = True)
      coll.ensure_index([('raw_value', pymongo.DESCENDING)], background = True)
      coll.ensure_index([('time_stamp', pymongo.DESCENDING), ('raw_value', pymongo.DESCENDING)], background = True)

  coll.insert(json_doc)
```

So that is the function I have. If I have ensure_index set to background = True any idea how long it blocks this thread calling that function?

Comment: They should not block at all, just receive acknowledgement from the server. The shell blocks for some silly reason I can't remember. The pymongo driver is not aync so technically it all blocks, but not for the duration of the index build. Which MongoDB version are you using at the server?

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I'm running 2.6.7.

Comment: So what are you asking then? How long does this take? Or how long does it "block" for? The possible ambiguity here was "does the call wait until the background build completes" which would have been a more succinct question. BTW The first index statement there is made redundant by the third index. You're just wasting space doing that since  queries that could use the first can also use the third index.

Comment: Yeah I see it was slightly ambiguous. The question was how long does the actual call to begin that index creation take. At the rate the data is coming in and how often this function is going to get called I am worried about it taking too long and dropping messages off the queue so I want to make it as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating new index on empty collection is quite fast, you can measure it by running following test

```
function howLong(){

    var t0 = new Date().valueOf();
    db.myCollection.ensureIndex({name: 1});
    var t1 = new Date().valueOf();

    return t1 - t0;
}
```

EnsureIndex will block until index is created. On my old laptop is says 0 :)

The same technique might be used to get approx "background" creation time of an index in mongoshell.

> Background indexing operations run in the background so that other
>   database operations can run while creating the index. However, the
>   **mongo shell session or connection** where you are creating the index
>   **will block** until the index build is complete.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-creation/#behavior

If you call ensureIndex early enough it will be quick, i.e. indexing 100 000 items on my machine (indexing by name of users collection) takes approx 350ms.

Subsequent calls to ensureIndex  (after it has been created ) will exit straightaway (with appropriate message) but I would not do it if i could. (i.e. the database is controlled by me and not shared with others) I would do the dedicated thread for index creation.

Since your collection will grow quite fast and you will create an index, make sure it fits into RAM [see here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/) so it might be worth to pre-aggregate the data while inserting.

Regarding checking the existence of collection, assuming your application is the only one writing to the db, you can list all the collection at the start-up and keep this information in memory.

There is interesting project from 10gen-Labs that seems to  addresses similar problems (java code though) Might be worth having look [High Volume Data Feed](https://github.com/10gen-labs/hvdf)

Comment: Great thanks for the response. Any idea if it is slower if I build the index in the background? And I was going to do that but I'm worried about multiple instances and my class not getting updated synchronously between instances.